# glutSwapBuffers() is not fast as glFlush()

Tags: c, opengl, glut

**Information**

I wrote my Rhythm game(like DJ Max, Jubeat, etc) code with using `C`, `OpenGL` and `GLUT`.

1. My custom display function is called every 10ms with `glutTimerFunc()`.
2. In my display funtion, I used `glFlush()` to draw notes with single buffer, it shows good speed but has some flickering.
3. When I changed `glFlush()` to `glutSwapBuffers()` with double buffers, its speed getting slower so the timer function is not called every 10ms exactly.

**Question**

How can I implement faster animation(or re-drawing) without any flickering that refresh the screen at every 10ms?

Here is my code.

**Code**

Init and start music and game.

```
void musicStart(int id) {
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(1600, 900);
    glutCreateWindow("Rhythm And Lines - Evnas");

    glutDisplayFunc(displayMainWindow);
    enter code hereglutKeyboardFunc(keyboardMainWindow);
    glutKeyboardUpFunc(keyboardUpMainWindow);
    glutTimerFunc(10, timerMainWindow, 1);

    score = 0;
    g_maxNotes = 6000;
    myTmpNotes = (TmpNote*)malloc(sizeof(TmpNote)*MAXSIZE);
    loadData(id);

    initMainWindow();
    playMusic(id);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

display function

```
void displayMainWindow(){
    int tmpIdx=0;
    int j,k;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    drawLines();

    if (line < g_maxNotes) {
        for (j = line; j < line+MAXSIZE; j++) {
            strcpy(myTmpNotes[tmpIdx].noteId, g_notes[j].noteId);
            myTmpNotes[tmpIdx].timeslice = g_notes[j].timeslice;
            myTmpNotes[tmpIdx].originIdx = j;
            tmpIdx++;
        }

        for (k=0; k<=MAXSIZE; k++) {
            printNoteGUI(myTmpNotes[k].noteId, k);
        }
    }
    highlightKey();

    sprintf(scoreStr, "%d", score);
    drawText(MAX_X/2, MAX_Y/2, scoreStr);

    //glFlush(); -> Fast but flickering
    glutSwapBuffers(); // -> No flickering but slow
}
```

timer functions that repeats display every 10ms

```
void timerMainWindow(){
    line++;

    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(10, timerMainWindow, 1);
}
```

I have to use only `C`, `OpenGL` and `GLUT` because is my school project's rule.

Comment: Do you have vsync enabled?

Comment: What's that `Sleep()` for?  You're already throttling the frame-rate via your `glutTimerFunc()` callback.

Comment: "How can I implement faster animation(or re-drawing) without any flickering that refresh the screen at every 10ms?" by using a 100Hz monitor and video mode.

Comment: @BDL No i disabled vsync

Comment: @genpfault i'm sorry, that was my mistake. i read some article that increase swapping speed by adding Sleep function. But for me there's no difference if i added or not. Sorry for that. I'll modify it.

Comment: @derhass I use 144Hz Monitor and video mode, nothing worse.

Comment: but 144 is not an integral multiple of 100. If your monitor displays a frame every 6.95ms, you simply cannot display a new image every 10ms.

Comment: I think if you disable vsync, you might see flickering. Since the game refresh rate might not match the monitor refresh rate.